# using language created in jetBrains MPS tool outside MPS tool / intellij idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, dsl, jetbrains-ide, mps

I have created my own small DSL using jetBrains MPS tool.
I am able to use this language inside MPS tool or with help of plugins in Intellij Idea too. I want to use this language outside MPS and Intellij. Idea lets say in any simple java project. Is there any way to export this language so that we can use it anywhere. can we create a jar or something of the language. **More specifically I want to use it in Eclipse**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly export your language as a standalone Java IDE - a dedicated tool basd on the IntelliJ platform that will only support editing code in the language that you package with it. The process of creating such an IDE is described at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD33/Building+standalone+IDEs+for+your+languages

Eclipse integration is currently not supported in MPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out mps maven plugin (https://github.com/JetBrains/mps-maven-plugin) to see if it works for you.